# How do I append sentiment values from oseti to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis, cjk

First post here!

After struggling with mecab and encodings I got oseti to work for Japanese sentiment analysis, where oseti.Analyzer() takes a string and prints a list with one value per sentence:

```
>>> import oseti
>>> analyzer = oseti.Analyzer()
>>> analyzer.analyze('心配です。でも好き。')
[-1.0, 1.0]
```

(Sorry, not 100% sure if it prints or just resturns the list)

I have a pandas dataframe with about 10,000 rows and want to create a new column (OS) with the mean value of the oseti.Analyzer output from a certain column (HD). Some of the HD cells have hundreds of sentences, rendering hundreds of sentiment values.

The line below gave an error message:

```
df['OS'] = sum((analyzer.analyze(df['HD']))) / len((analyzer.analyze(df['HD'])))

TypeError: Argument 'text' has incorrect type (expected str, got Series)
```

I am not sure what I should do. Isolate the string part of each HD observation? Convert the column to strings? Run oseti in a for loop before turning by CSV data into a Pandas dataframe?

If you couldn't tell by now, I'm a newbie and just starting out with Python and pandas. I have gone through some of the usual Web courses and videos, but have not seen anything about oseti or directly applicable examples from other modules.

Comment: It looks like analyzer.analyze takes one input, but you passing in all the inputs. You can try df['HD'].apply(analyzer.analyze)  which will pass each result individually, then returning a list of the values, but  you'll have to change the way you sum. Seeing the output of df['HD'].apply(analyzer.analyze) should help though

Comment: @oppressionslayer, your suggested code `df['HD'].apply(analyzer.analyze)` gave one list of values per row. This is a great step - now, as you mentioned, I just have to calculate the averages...

Comment: Would flattening the list help? If so you could use: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html then the sum should work

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

With flattening as suggested by @oppressionslayer, I came up with the below code that may not be the most elegant but does the job. Thank you so much for the help.

```
OStemp = np.array(df['HD'].apply(analyzer.analyze))
OStemp.flatten()
df['OS'] = [(sum(i) / len(i)) for i in OStemp]
```

Comment: Sorry for the many comments, but I found a shorter way to do this without flattening:
`df['OS'] = [(sum(o) / len(o)) for o in df['HD'].apply(analyzer.analyze)]`